# Tool tip text in a PdfTextFormField

Tags: pdf-generation, itext7

How do I add a tool tip/help text to a PdfTextFormField with itext 7?

I create the field using the `PdfFormField.createText(..)` method, but I have no idea how to add the tool tip and can't find relevant documentation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A field in a PDF file is defined using a *field dictionary* and it is visualized using one or more *widget annotation dictionaries.* A field as such is invisible; it is made visible through annotations.

If you read the PDF specification, you will notice that you can add a `/TU` to a widget annotation. This key is used to specify a *user name*. This is somewhat misleading terminology because the `/TU` key isn't there to store the name of a user; it's there to store a name for human consumption: a name that is easy for a user to understand.

For instance: a field name could be named `mgtMtgDt` and its user(friendly) name could be `Management meeting date`.

In iText, you set that user name using the `setUserName()` method, for instance:

```
field.setUserName("Management meeting date");
```

Most PDF viewers use this `/TU` value to show a tooltip for the field.

Comment: Bruno, thank you for the response (and sorry it has been a bit since I've worked on the project). I took a look, but I can't find the `setUserName` method in iText 7. I found it for iText 5, but I would really like to use the newer version.